# FlatList not scrolling (horizontal) in React-Native expo

Tags: react-native-flatlist

I have two child components that are rendered in App.js and my problem is with the second child component (BottomHorizontalBoxes.js). I can render items from API but it's not scrolling in FlatList, it is bouncing back to the starting position without showing all the items. Also if item.title (text) has more letters, gray rectangle box becomes bigger. I want to keep its size the same. I think I have some problems with wrapper containers and their styles.

I searched for the problem and tried many solutions but couldn't find it yet. I added video link too.

[YouTube Link](https://youtube.com/shorts/EWuJT3Fg6tI?feature=share)

---

**App.js codes**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import BestRated from './components/BestRated';
import BottomHorizontalBoxes from './components/BottomHorizontalBoxes';




export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BestRated />
      <BottomHorizontalBoxes />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'left',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginTop: 100,
  },
});
```

---

**BestRated.js codes**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const BestRated = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Best Rated!</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default BestRated

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        width: '80%',
        marginBottom: 15,
    },

    text: {
        color: '#818181',
        width: '80%',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    }
})
```

---

**BottomHorizontalBoxes.js codes**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const BottomHorizontalBoxes = () => {
const foodList = [
        {there is a long JSON data, I didn't copy it here to save rows}, 
]

const foodListWithoutFirst4 = foodList.splice(4)
    console.log(foodListWithoutFirst4);


    return (
        <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <FlatList
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
                data={foodListWithoutFirst4}       
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <View style={styles.itemViewContainer}>
                            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default BottomHorizontalBoxes

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    itemViewContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#d9d9d9',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 100,
        width: '90%',
        borderRadius: 10,
    },

}
)
```

I tried contentContainerStyle, flex:1 and the other styling things in FlatList and Text container.

Answer (score -1):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space.)*

Solved!

I'm trying for hours and now I got the solution. In BottomHorizontalBoxes.js styling; itemViewContainer: {}, I just changed `width:'80%'`, to `width: 200`, and added `marginRight: 20`, now it's all OK!